# How to redirect properly in node express using html button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to link my html page to other pages via express render
and my directory looks like this

```
app.js
/views
 |---/images
 |---home.ejs
 |---other.ejs
```

and the code inside app.js looks like this:

```
const express= require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const app=express(); 

app.use( express.static( "views" ) );

app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.listen(3000,()=>console.log("listening at Port 3000..."));

app.get('/home',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('./home.ejs');
   });

app.get('/other',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('./other.ejs');
   });


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.redirect('/home');
   });
```

and the code inside home.ejs looks like this:

```
<button onclick="location.href='other'">
```

but when I run the site and click on the button it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/home/other` whereas, I need it to redirect me to `http://localhost:3000/other`
I know I'm making some rookie mistake but I can't seem to pin point it at the moment, any help is greatly appreciated

**Note**
The given above code is a simplification of my problem, as it would be very difficult to write the entire code. so if I've made any mistakes in the explaination then please ignore them and try to understand the essence of the Q

Comment: Use a URL relative to the root by adding a slash: `<button onclick="location.href='/other'">`

Comment: @blex oh I completely forgot about that, thank you so much if you can post that as an answer I'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 0):

try to:

```
<button onclick="window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com'">
```